# Windows Partitions missing

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I do have two physical disks, one 120 SSD to contain an OS and one HDD to contain data. My Ubuntu is installed, of course, in the SSD and my HDD is partitioned into two disks. Since I did it on Windows, it is not well-recognised by Linux distros. When I was in Arch, I succeeded it mounting by using 'ldmtool create all' and then setting mount points. But in Ubuntu, it is automatically mounted, and that is the partition I need the least, because it contains downloadable data like movies and series. The other one, the missing one, contains my project files which I haven't backed up yet. May I know if there is a way to mount the other one and use it as normal until I have finished my project?

[Here is the picture to the result of fdisk -l for the HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXx1x.png)

in /dev/sda3 I clearly 2.7T although in Windows, it has been partitioned into two drives called "Data" and "Studies".

[Here is the picture to my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PkUP.png)

In here, of course, /dev/sda3 has been mounted, but in there, only the folders and files from "Data" is visible and shown.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1266969/edit) and add all the new information requested by everyone. Screenshots should be uplaoded to imgur.com and linked in the question. Please do not put screenshots of texts (if asked for) in the terminal. Copy and paste the text from the terminal into the question.

Comment: Do you actually have *missing* (deleted) partitions, or are they just unmountable? It's also unclear of the "missing" partition is actually your Windows (system) partition or if it's just a data partition. In that case, what file system is used?

Comment: @user535733 I do not have access to Windows since I'm not dual booting, but here they are in fidsk -l.

Comment: @user535733 Ah, I have untouched the Windows hard disk throughout the time, I have only worked with SSD for installation.

Comment: @Nmath I think I do not have deleted partitions since I have the HDD untouched throughout the process. And it isn't unmountable since half of it was mounted so maybe it's partially mounted? I have made two partitions to a disk in Windows, and the second partition is missing when automatically mounted here.

Comment: There is no such thing as "half mounted" so I would reevaluate your assumptions based on this line of reasoning.  `sda1` and `sda2` are system partitions. The only other partition on the disk is `sda3`.  If there was ever a `sda4`, it's not there now.  `sda3` is not divisible into any more partitions.